# how to prevent mutiple registration of a single event handler in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a `<div>` box displaying search message and some radio button for recent message. There is  link  option for slide toggle.

When you click on that link it will show some input field and check box and radio button. And at the same time the text of link change to hide option. If you click on that it will hide all the input and checkbox option.

When I refreash the whole page its working properly but when that paticular box or part is refreashing then the box is hiding and imediately hides. If you refresh that portion **n** number of times the box is going on toggling continously. I think the problem is in registration of event handler. So please give me some solution.

CODE :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".SideBar-blockheader1").click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".SideBar-blockcontent1").slideToggle("fast");
  });

  $(".SideBar-optionheader").click(function() {
    $(".SideBar-optioncontent").slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).text($(this).text() == $("#hideopt").attr('value') ?  $("#showopt").attr('value') : $("#hideopt").attr('value'));
  });

  $(".SideBar-optionheader").text($("#showopt").attr('value'));
  $(".SideBar-optioncontent").hide();
});
```

Comment: How do you refresh only that **part**? Are you using ajax? Do you use .NET's update panel?

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't provided code, I suspect you are using .click(). For jQuery 1.7+ you should be using `.on()` in delegate mode (the element you bind to is an ancestor, not the clickable element itself) or `.delegate()` if pre jQ 1.7.

For example:

```
$('someAncestor').on('click', 'a.specialLink', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // the rest of your code for the click handler
})
```

"someAncestor" is any valid selector that is an ancestor of your link that will not be destroyed, rebuilt, or otherwise manipulated after the DOM is built. It doesn't have to be the direct ancestor.

**[updated below after seeing code sample and comments]**

There are a few things going on. First, `.on()` will only work if you're using jQuery 1.7+. Next, `.on()` can be invoked a few different ways (I wrote about it here: http://gregpettit.ca/2011/jquery-events-its-on/) and you need to be invoking it while delegating an ancestor listener, not simply as a substitute for click. Next, you haven't provided code for your attempted update, only for the original code; it's hard to tell what "didn't work" about trying to use `.on()`. Moving along, I'm not actually sure what this line is meant to do:

```
$(this).text($(this).text() == $("#hideopt")...etc...
```

I can't think of why you would want to try to treat a jQuery object as a variable. I'm not saying the code is wrong, I'm just saying I don't get it. Also, I hate ternary operators... which is part of the reason I don't get it. I much prefer readable conditionals. ;-)

Next, you're calling preventDefault() on "e" but you're not passing "e" into your functions. You might just be getting a JavaScript error, period. (e is undefined)

Then there's `attr("value")` which I believe should actually work. But why not use `.val()` if it is indeed a node that HAS a value attribute?

Finally, there is tonnes of room for caching your objects. Every time you see that an object is being used more than once, you can benefit (to varying degrees of performance and legibility) from caching it. I have not updated the code with any caching, though-- that's really something for a whole other "How can I best cache my objects?" question.

Anyhow... to solve the problem, you first have to choose a valid ancestor. This can be any ancestor that isn't destroyed during the process of loading in your new data. This could be anything, but the closest ancestor is the best. It might be a section wrapper, but if you're truly desperate it could be a page wrapper or even the body tag. If you bind to document, you're reproducing the deprecated `.live()` function, which I definitely recommend against. I have used a placeholder selector, "`.section`" but *you* need to figure out what an appropriate ancestor is on your page.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".section").on("click", ".SideBar-blockheader1", function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault(); // probably not necessary if there's no default click behaviour
    $(".SideBar-blockcontent1").slideToggle("fast");
  });

  $(".section").on("click", ".SideBar-optionheader", function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault(); // probably not necessary if there's no default click behaviour
    $(".SideBar-optioncontent").slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).text($(this).text() == $("#hideopt").val() ?$("#showopt").val() : $("#hideopt").val());
  });

  $(".SideBar-optionheader").text($("#showopt").val());
  $(".SideBar-optioncontent").hide();
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".SideBar-blockheader1").click(function(){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".SideBar-blockcontent1").slideToggle("fast");
  });
  $(".SideBar-optionheader").click(function() {            
            $(".SideBar-optioncontent").slideToggle("fast");
            $(this).text($(this).text() == $("#hideopt").attr('value') ? $("#showopt").attr('value') : $("#hideopt").attr('value'));
          });
  
  $(".SideBar-optionheader").text($("#showopt").attr('value'));
        $(".SideBar-optioncontent").hide();          
 });

Comment: I don't know what sliding stop means. ;-) But anyhow I have provided an extensive reply; see edit.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a method, called `data()` which can be used to extract the attached handler information of an HTML element. You can see if the element has already a click handler, and if it has, then stop re-attaching another handler to it.

```
if(typeof $('#id').data('events').click == 'object')
{
    // A click handler is already attached
}
else
{
    // No click handler; Attach one;
}
```